# React fullstack architecture: When adding a react front-end to a node/express application, what aspects does react's state generally handle?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-fullstack

I have a fully built node/express application that I want to add react to in order to practice that relationship in full stack applications. I've built apps in react before, and in node, but never together and I am confused about how react fits into the MVC architecture.

In a react-node full stack application does react state then handle all of the data I was previously passing into my `ejs` views?

I have been looking through tutorials on full stack applications with node and react, but they only seem to go into issues like how does react fetch data from the back end, or how to set up the configuration, 
but I get that part, I just don't understand what react does in a full stack application, what part of the model-controller-view architecture of a node/express backend app does react take over? How are the responsibilities split between the backend and front end?

So for example, I'm working with a reddit-clone type app so when you click on a post title to see the post my controller queries the database for that post and then passes it to the view as `{post}`:

```js
show(req, res, next){
        postQueries.getPost(req.params.id, (error, post) => {
            if(error || post == null){
                res.redirect(404, "/");
            } else {
                res.render("posts/show", {post});
            }
        });
    },
```

So when I add a front-end with react, would that `{post}` object then be something handled by react? So react would fetch that data and use it in a post component to create what is currently my view `show.ejs` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So when I add a front-end with react, would that {post} object then be something handled by react? So react would fetch that data and use it in a post component to create what is currently my view show.ejs file?

Yes. The `show.ejs` would be a React `view` or a `page` that contains a `component` to handle how to show it.

To simplify:

React -- is a virtual DOM, so it'll swap `views`/`containers`/`components` in and out based upon `events` (like clicking a button), which in turn, will: retrieve, display, manipulate and/or send data to the API. In development, it is completely separate from your back-end. All the routing will be handled by a front-end router package. In production, all of the front-end `src` code is compiled into a `dist` or `build` folder that contains your assets (images, fonts, css) and most importantly [bundle.js file(s) that are then served by express](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/fullstack-mern-kit/blob/master/server/index.js#L20-L24).

Express + some database -- will act as your API where it'll CRUD data based upon the front-end request(s). If your app is a MPA (multiple page application), then a common practice is to delineate your back-end routes from your [front-end routes](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/fullstack-mern-kit/blob/master/client/src/routes/index.js#L28) with a [/api/](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/fullstack-mern-kit/blob/master/routes/user.js#L10) prefix. In production, if express doesn't recognize the route (it's not a `/api/` request), then it'll fall back into the front-end `bundle.js` file where it'll be handled by the [front-end router](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/fullstack-mern-kit/blob/master/client/src/routes/index.js#L29).

**See a working example here**: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/fullstack-mern-kit (`client` is the frontend, everything else is the backend)

Or

**See a working codesandbox** (where I'm making a `GET` request to an [API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users) that returns `json`):

[image: Edit Restructured App]

---

For your example above, your `show` controller will just be sending `JSON` (or a `string` message) back to the frontend (redirects will happen on the frontend via a router -- like `react-router-dom`):

```
show(req, res, next){
        postQueries.getPost(req.params.id, (error, post) => {
            if(error || post == null){
                // res.status(404).send("Unable to locate posts.");
                res.status(404).json({ err: Unable to locate posts });
            } else {
                res.status(200).json({ post });
            }
        });
    },
```

You can even simplify the above using `async/await`:

```
const show = async (req, res, done) => {
        try {
           const post = await postQueries.getPost(req.params.id);
           res.status(200).json({ post });
        } catch(err) {
           // res.status(404).send("Unable to locate posts.");
           res.status(404).json({ err: Unable to locate posts });
        }
    };
```

And then the React front-end handles the response.

Comment: Ohh!! That makes a lot of sense, thank you! This is super helpful and clarifying

Comment: You bet. The above contains a lot of (vastly oversimplified) information. I'd highly recommend investing in this Udemy course as it covers all things React: https://www.udemy.com/react-2nd-edition/

Comment: Thanks! I have done a lot of react apps that are just client side so the simplification is fine, I just needed a broad explanation of React's role in a full stack application because I've only ever done either just backend or just front end.